# How do I sort list of numeric strings without parsing?

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting, c#-4.0

I have a list of strings with high values (greater than int 32), How do i sort them in ascending order without parsing?

```
List = {"4852154879","2652154879","9852154879","1952154879","0652154879"}
```

I tried parsing as below, but looking for an alternative and better approach without parsing

```
Sorted List = List.OrderBy(x => long.Parse(x.serialNumber)).ToList();
```

Comment: *Why* are you looking for an alternative approach? What do you want to happen if any values aren't valid integers? Might they be negative? Might they be out of the range of int64? Might they have whitespace?

Comment: Do you even need to maintain the list as strings? Any reason you're not converting it to a `List<long>` to start with?

Comment: Left pad them all with zeroes to the length of the longest string in the list (assuming they are all integers, and not floating point numbers).

Comment: @JonSkeet no in this case, the numbers could be 9,10 or 11 digit long without any negatives, white space or alphabets.

Comment: Alphabetically.

Comment: I just dont understand why `Parse` isnt the best option?

Comment: @JonSkeet you have more _in depth_ knowledge than I do, if OP is reasonably sure that the strings will always be valid `long` is there any faster method than parsing?

Comment: @maccettura: Not *simple* ones. You could pad with zeroes, but that's going to create a lot of extra strings, which may well perform *worse* than parsing. I would first perform appropriate measurements to check whether the simplest and clearest solution is a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, I almost certainly *wouldn't* take the approach below. I'd either convert the input to a `List<long>`, or just use the code you've already got, at least until I'd absolutely proved that it wasn't good enough.

However, as this is quite an interesting problem, let's try to write a fast `IComparer<T>`. This relies on:

- No negative values
- Possible zero padding, but no other padding
- Assume that all values are valid

When comparing two values, if the values are the same length, we can just use an ordinal string comparison. Otherwise:

- Find the number of leading zeroes in each string, to work out the "logical" length of each
- If the resulting logical lengths are different, whichever is longer is bigger
- Otherwise, compare the strings from just after the leading zeroes

This manages to perform each comparison with no object allocations.

Something like (completely untested):

```
public sealed class NumericComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public static readonly IComparer<string> Instance { get; } = new NumericComparer();

    private NumericComparer() {}

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x.Length == y.Length)
        {
            return string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        }
        int xIndex = FindFirstNonZeroIndex(x);
        int yIndex = FindFirstNonZeroIndex(y);
        int lengthComparison = (x.Length - xIndex).CompareTo(y.Length - yIndex);
        if (lengthComparison != 0)
        {
            return lengthComparison;
        }
        return string.Compare(x, xIndex, y, yIndex, x.Length, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    private static int FindFirstNonZeroIndex(string text)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] != '0')
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        // All zeroes? Return text.Length - 1, so that we treat this as
        // "0".
        return text.Length - 1;
    }
}
```

You can then sort a list in-place with:

```
list.Sort(NumericComparer.Instance);
```

Now I've just been benchmarking this... and it looks like it's roughly the same performance as parsing, as far as I can tell. Actually very slightly worse - but much better than the padding form.

Benchmarking code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

public class Program
{
    private readonly List<string> list;

    public Program()
    {
        list = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000)
            .Select(_ => GenerateValue())
            .ToList();
    }

    // Just to test the impact of copying...
    [Benchmark]
    public List<string> NoSorting()
    {
        var copy = new List<string>(list);
        return copy;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public List<string> NoParsing()
    {
        var copy = new List<string>(list);
        copy.Sort(NumericComparer.Instance);
        return copy;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public List<string> WithParsing() => list.OrderBy(x => long.Parse(x)).ToList();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<Program>();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public List<string> WithPadding()
    {
        int maxLength = list.Max(y => y.Length);
        return list.OrderBy(x => x.PadLeft(maxLength, '0')).ToList();
    }        

    // Use the same seed on all tests
    static readonly Random random = new Random(1);
    static string GenerateValue()
    {
        // Up to 11 digits...
        long leading = random.Next(100000);
        long trailing = random.Next(1000000);
        long value = leading * 1000000 + trailing;
        // Pad to 9, 10 or 11 randomly
        int width = random.Next(3) + 9;
        return value.ToString().PadLeft(width, '0');
    }
}
// NumericComparer as per post
```

Results:

```
      Method |         Mean |        Error |      StdDev |
------------ |-------------:|-------------:|------------:|
   NoSorting |     473.3 us |     9.359 us |    25.62 us |
   NoParsing |  46,684.7 us |   932.466 us | 1,366.80 us |
 WithParsing |  43,149.8 us |   790.116 us |   700.42 us |
 WithPadding | 275,843.4 us | 3,083.376 us | 2,733.33 us |
```

Alternative idea, which is definitely simpler:

- If the strings are the same length, compare ordinally
- Otherwise, just parse both

(I haven't benchmarked that yet.)

Comment: Could it be done simpler by doing a linq order by, first by length then by value?

Comment: Only if there are no leading zeroes in the data

Comment: @Grax - Right, just realized that.

Comment: @Jon Small correction - inside `string.Compare`, `x.Length` should be `x.Length - xIndex`

Comment: @IvanStoev: Nope, that's deliberate - it's just "any max length". I could have used `int.MaxValue`. We want to compare from the given indexes to the end of the string.

Comment: Nevermind, you are right of course. Just a habit from `Substring` method which does not allow such freedom :)

Comment: @JonSkeet - I think there is a bug in this, as it gives the wrong results in a test I did. I think it might be that your `int lengthComparison` should be `int lengthComparison = (x.Length - xIndex).CompareTo(y.Length - yIndex);`

Comment: And I should mention, posting a comment suggesting there might be a bug in Jon Skeet's code scared the hell out of me.

Comment: @hatchet: You're right - the longer value is bigger, so it should just be the length. For some reason I thought I needed to invert it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out a Least Significant Digit Radix Sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Least_significant_digit_radix_sorts

This method will not require any parsing, and it will sort the strings correctly because the string values of numbers are in the correct order. It also doesn't require any padding, even though that's really not an issue :)

However, note that you will have to code this yourself, and if you are not concerned about efficiency it will be simpler to use Hatchet/Mong Zhu's solution.

Answer (score 2):

As [hatchet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/834261/hatchet) already suggested here is the padding with `0`'s approach

```
List<string> temp = new List<string> { "4852154879", "2652154879", "9852154879", "1952154879", "0652154879" };
int maxLength = temp.Max(y=>y.Length);
temp = temp.OrderBy(x=>x.PadLeft(maxLength, '0')).ToList();
```

Disclaimer: this approach will of course fail if the numbers are not pure `int` or `long` but floating point (as pointed out in comments).

EDIT:

as suggested by hatched and due to the development in the answers here, I will add this point:

you can improve the speed about 5% in Jon's benchmark with this change:

```
temp.OrderBy(x => (x.Length==maxLength) ? x : x.PadLeft(maxLength, '0')).ToList();
```

Comment: Note that this is going to call `temp.Max(y => y.Length)` a *lot* of times, potentially.

Comment: Looks good.  Alternately, the value in PadLeft could be a known max length for the values.  Also important to emphasize that this solution fails silently if the data is anything but an integer value.  To Jon Skeet's point, it would probably be wise to compute the max length prior to the orderBy call so that is doesn't keep getting recomputed for no reason.

Comment: It's also going to create lots of strings - up to two per comparison. There are more efficient approaches, but they're not simple.

Comment: @JonSkeet valid point, changed it. Was too hasty to write it in one line :)

Comment: @JonSkeet  can you recommend a place to learn more about the downsides of string creations like this? Now that you mention it, I can see it using memory and that having to be garbage collected, but I'd like to understand better

Comment: @Grax: That's about it... but I suspect it will be significant. Benchmarking now...

Comment: @MongZhu - you can improve the speed about 5% in Jon's benchmark with this change: `temp.OrderBy(x => (x.Length==maxLength) ? x : x.PadLeft(maxLength, '0')).ToList();`

Comment: @hatchet I see that there was a vivid discussion about this problem, while I was gone. I will edit my answer and incorporate your suggestion. Thanx mate.

Answer (score -3):

I guess you should use `List<long>`  instead of     `List<string>`

```
List<long> list = new List<long>(){4852154879,2652154879,9852154879,1952154879,0652154879};
            list = list.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: The question states that the OP has strings, and that is the crux of the question. Your answer doesn't address that at all.

Answer (score -8):

sort them as strings ,  and it will work.  Sorting striungs does the alphabet but also orders numbers correctly